# Determining distance in R?

Tags: r, point, buffer

I am trying to simply draw a 1km radius around a point, but I am unfamiliar with how all of it works precisely. This is what I have:

```
d = data.frame(lat = 10, lon = 10, ID = 1)
coordinates(d) = ~lon + lat
proj4string(d) = raster::crs(sp_df)
buf = rgeos::gBuffer(d, width = 1)
```

This is what buf looks like after:

```
> buf
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 1 
extent      : 9, 11, 9, 11  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Now, what I don't know is what 1 means... I would like to have a 1km radius around a point.

Comment: `buf` is a single circle (1 feature) of radius 1 unit in the units of `d`, which are the units of the crs (coordinate system) of `sp_df` which might be km or might be degrees... what is it?

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment, I read this before. I am not familiar (at all) about how the units work. So `buf` and `sp_df` has the same crs, and the width of the circle is 1 unit - but what does this unit represent?

Comment: Its all degrees. Try `plot(buf);plot(d,add=TRUE)` and you should see a circle and a point. But the point is at 10N 10E (Africa?) and the "circle" is a 10degree circle... So not what you want, I guess...

Comment: Yea, indeed... the 10, 10 are just random numbers... It is indeed not what I want, because the distance from 9, 9 to 10, 10 (one radius) is 156.35km, I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the code below using `sf` package instead of `sp`. Also you will find a function to find the UTM zone to transform your data if you need work with meters instead of degrees. And some great map interactive visualizations using `mapview`.

```
# Load libraries
library('sf') # manage spatial vector data
library('mapview') # interactive map visualization in R

# Load data
point <- data.frame('lat' = -34.909207,
                   'lon' = -56.163402,
                   'id' = '1')
# Create sf object
# Assign 4326 as the coordinate reference system (CRS) because 'lat' and 'lon'
# are on degrees
sf_point <- st_as_sf(point, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Plot point
mapView(sf_point)
```

[image: plotmap]

```
# Transform to planar coordinates to use meters: check UTM zone first from
# lat and lon values

# Find UTM zone number by longitude
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186496/determining-utm-zone-to-convert-from-longitude-latitude
long2UTM <- function(lon, lat) {

  zone = (floor((lon + 180)/6) %% 60) + 1

  if (lat < 0) {
    zone = paste("WGS 84 / UTM zone ", zone, "S", sep = "")
  } else {
    zone = paste("WGS 84 / UTM zone ", zone, "N", sep = "")
  }
  return(zone)
}

zone <- long2UTM(lon = point$lon, lat = point$lat)
print(zone)

[1] "WGS 84 / UTM zone 21S"

# Find UTM code
EPSG <- rgdal::make_EPSG() # Make a data frame of EPSG projection codes
code <- EPSG[grep(zone, x = EPSG$note),]$code # Search zone code in df of EPSG

# Transform from lat/lon in degrees to planar coordinates (utm)
sf_point_utm <- st_transform(sf_point, crs = code)

# Create buffer (1km ~ 1000m)
st_point_buffer <- st_buffer(sf_point_utm, dist = 1000)

# Plot point + buffer
mapView(sf_point) + mapView(st_point_buffer)
```

[image: plotBuffer]

Comment: Awsome!!! Thanks so much for the detailed explanation and the effort! Much appreciated